# Mock Httpservletrequest and requestcontext

Tags: unit-testing, junit, mockito, springmockito

I am trying to mock `RequestContext` and `HttpServletRequest` classes/interfaces but they not working.

code:

```java
@Override
public Object run() {

    String accessToken= "";

    ctx = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();
    HttpServletRequest request = ctx.getRequest();

    String requestedServiceUri = request.getRequestURI();

    //...
```

Mock I have written

```java
//...

HttpServletRequest request = Mockito.mock(HttpServletRequest.class);
RequestContext requestContext = Mockito.mock(RequestContext.class); 

when(request.getHeader("principal")).thenReturn("abcd");
when(request.getHeader("authorization")).thenReturn("authtoken");
when(request.getRequestURI()).thenReturn("abcd-tt/api/v1/softwaremanagement");

when(requestContext.getCurrentContext()).thenReturn(requestContext);
when(requestContext.getRequest()).thenReturn(request);

//...
```

I am getting `MissingMethodInvocation` exception. Not sure if this right way of testing this method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to mock the static call for the context.

```java
//Arrange
HttpServletRequest request = Mockito.mock(HttpServletRequest.class);
when(request.getHeader("principal")).thenReturn("abcd");
when(request.getHeader("authorization")).thenReturn("authtoken");
when(request.getRequestURI()).thenReturn("abcd-tt/api/v1/softwaremanagement");

RequestContext requestContext = Mockito.mock(RequestContext.class);
when(requestContext.getRequest()).thenReturn(request);

PowerMockito.mockStatic(RequestContext.class);    
when(RequestContext.getCurrentContext()).thenReturn(requestContext);
```

Do not forget to include

```java
@PrepareForTest(RequestContext.class)
```

so that the mocked static calls will be available when invoked.

Comment: it helped to fix the issue. Thank you