# JUnit Test: NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, junit, javabeans

I'm getting the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1373)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1119)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545)
... 56 more
```

Full stacktrace [here](https://pastebin.com/ZHAEQnLz)

And here's my JUnit:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestConfig.class)
@Transactional
public class Prueba {

    private static final String FIRSTNAME = "TestFirstName";
    private static final String LASTNAME = "TestLastName";
    private static final String EMAIL = "test@mail.com";
    private static final String PASSWORD = "TestPassword";
    private static final String PHONENUMBER = "00000000";
    private static final String ROLE = "USER";

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Autowired
    private UserHibernateDao userDao; // THIS SEEMS TO BE THE ISSUE!
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    private long user_id;

    @Before
    @Transactional
    public void setUp() {

        User u;
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            u = new User();
            u.setFirstName(i + FIRSTNAME + i);
            u.setLastName(i + LASTNAME + i);
            u.setEmail(i + EMAIL);
            u.setLocked(false);
            em.persist(u);
            if (i == 10) {
                this.user_id = u.getUserid();
            }

        }
    }

    @Rollback
    @Test
    public void testCreate() {
        final User user =  userDao.create(FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, EMAIL, PASSWORD, PHONENUMBER, ROLE);
        assertNotNull(user);
    }
}
```

The issue as I pointed out in the code seems to be when I autowire UserHibernateDao.

Here's my TestConfig:

```
@ComponentScan({"src.main.java.ar.edu.itba.paw.persistence",   })
@Configuration
public class TestConfig {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        final SimpleDriverDataSource ds = new SimpleDriverDataSource();
        ds.setDriverClass(JDBCDriver.class);
        ds.setUrl("jdbc:hsqldb:mem:paw");
        ds.setUsername("ha");
        ds.setPassword("");
        return ds;
    }

     @Bean
     public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean getEntityManagerFactory() {
         final LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
         factoryBean.setPackagesToScan("ar.edu.itba.paw.models");
         factoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
         final JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
         factoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
         final Properties properties = new Properties();
         properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
         properties.setProperty("hibernate.search.default.directory_provider", "filesystem");
         properties.setProperty("hibernate.search.default.indexBase", "lucene/indexes");
         properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect");
         properties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
         properties.setProperty("format_sql", "true");
         factoryBean.setJpaProperties(properties);
         return factoryBean;
       }



     @Bean
     public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(final EntityManagerFactory emf) {
          return new JpaTransactionManager(emf);
     }

     @Bean
        public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
            return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        }
}
```

And here's how my packages look:

[image]

Any ideas on how to fix it?

I tried changing my 
    @ComponentScan({"src.main.java.ar.edu.itba.paw.persistence",   })

to 
    @ComponentScan({"ar.edu.itba.paw.persistence",   })

But this doesn't work either.

Also here's my [UserHibernateDao class](https://pastebin.com/xCSQR3mq).

Comment: Please share the full error stack . org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException part will show the exact component that fails . It is not related to the classes you have shared

Comment: @R.G Ok I just posted it here https://pastebin.com/ZHAEQnLz

Comment: 1. @ComponentScan(<packageName>) seems to have an additional back-slash at the beginning . 2. Please share the UserHibernateDao class. How is this class made a bean ?

Comment: That back slash was a typo sorry. Here's UserHIbernateDao https://pastebin.com/eBRG3AvX.

Comment: You are wiring HttpServletRequest to a Repository which is not a recommended way. For this test to work , you will need to mock HttpServletRequest

Comment: Could you please tell me how to mock it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51564904/mock-httpservletrequest-and-requestcontext does this help ?

Comment: The best way is to create an User object with all what is required at Controller , call the repository method with that user. That will separate out the layers neatly and you can test Repository with components only required at that layer

Comment: @R.G I updated my UserHibernateDao class without  HttpServletRequest however the problem persists. I don't know what else to try.  https://pastebin.com/xCSQR3mq

Comment: Could you please update the question with the latest error stack ?

Comment: Only reason I can think of is that , it should be @ComponentScan("ar.edu.itba.paw.persistence") , other than that it looks perfect for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was apparently during setup because of em.persist. I changed it to:

```
@Before
@Transactional
public void setUp() {

    User u;
    for (int i = 10; i < 50; i++) {
        u = new User(i+FIRSTNAME, i+LASTNAME, i+EMAIL, PASSWORD, PHONENUMBER, ROLE, LANGUAGE);
        em.merge(u);
        if (i == 10) {
            this.user_id = u.getUserid();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The class that you try to @Autowired shoud be annotated with @Service or @Component